# Adding Contextual Links to Ctools Custom Content Type Plugin

Tags: chaos-tool-suite, navigation

Ctools custom content type called Custom Panes shows contextual links when you have access permission and you hover over the pane (much like a block shows the contextual links) which allows you to easily configure the content of the pane.  After creating my own plugin that is similar to Custom Panes content type (with a few custom fields), I noticed that I do not have contextual links when I hover over my custom panes. I'm wondering if I can set that in the $plugin definition to show contextual links or what the work around would be.  I found the template function the panels uses to `template_preprocess_panels_pane(&$vars)` which actually looks for `$vars['content']->content['#contextual_links']`.  I'm wondering if there is a way to add contextual links to custom ctools content type plugins?

Any advice would be great!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do that, what you can do is you can implement a `hook_menu_alter` and do this.

```
function YOUR-MODULE_menu_alter(&$items) {
  $items['YOUR-PLUGIN-PATH/%ctools_export_ui/edit']['context'] = MENU_CONTEXT_PAGE | MENU_CONTEXT_INLINE;
}
```

and then add your contextual link to your object. If it a block you can add below code in to your `hook_block_view`.

```
$block['content']['#contextual_links'] = array(
  'YOUR-CUSTOM-PLUGIN' => array('YOUR-PLUGIN-PATH', array($delta, 'edit'))
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the render callback of your custom CTools Content Type include file you can provide `admin_links`.

Here is an example pane that has a companion edit page at URL `admin/config/custom/my_custom_pane_settings`

```
<?php

$plugin = array(
  'title' => t('Custom Pane'),
  'single' => TRUE,
  'render callback' => 'my_custom_pane_render',
  'defaults' => array(),
  'category' => t('Page elements'),
  'edit form' => 'my_custom_pane_edit_form',
);

function my_custom_pane_edit_form($form, &$form_state) {
  return $form;
}

function my_custom_pane_render($subtype, $conf, $args, $context) {

  // Output.
  $block = new stdClass();

  // Define pane title & content.
  $block->title = 'Default pane title';
  $block->content = 'My custom pane content';

  // Add custom contextual links.
  $block->admin_links = array(
    'my_custom_pane' => array(
      'title' => t('Edit my custom pane'),
      'href' => 'admin/config/custom/my_custom_pane_settings',
      'query' => array(
        'destination' => current_path(),
      ),
    ),
  );

  return $block;
}
```